# XML (De-)Serialization in .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

In the .NET framework 4.5, what are the options to serialize / deserialize a defined set of classes to and from XML, and what are their respective advantages / disadvantages?

There may be an answer that applies to framework 4.5, but I couldn't find one with the search.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean what are the options in compare to older .NET fwk versions? There is and as I recall always have been System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer class that, allows to serialize / deserialize any calls to/from stream. You can decorate serialized classes with attributes to customize the output XML.

Comment: I'm asking for all options in 4.5. There is at least the XMLSerializer, DataContractSerializer and the always popular "roll-your-own". I'm asking what their respective advantages are, as well as what other alternatives exist, which might include popular 3rd party libraries.

Comment: DataContractSerializer has been around since .net 3 so it's nothing new either. Anyway, main differences between XmlSerializer  and DataContractSerializer are that, firstly,  DataContractSerializer does not support attributes (which makes it kind of useless for general usage) and, secondly, that it serializes only properties marked with DataMember attribute while XmlSerializer serializes alle public properties, except those marked with XmlIgnore attribute.